# Nested childs in lazy loaded module on Angular

Tags: angular

I have a problem with nested children routes in angular. My routes registration:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NavigationComponent } from './container/container.component';
import { Tab1Component } from './tab1/tab1.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'nav',
        component: NavigationComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'tab1',
                component: Tab1Component
            }
        ]
    },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'nav', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

export const MyRouting = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

(Note this is a lazy loaded module and the base route is /section/).

I can access to NavigationComponent with this URL: `http://localhost:4200/section/nav/` and it is showed correctly.

Then I just access to `http://localhost:4200/section/nav/tab1` and NavigationComponent is rendered again. If I remove `component: NavigationComponent,` it works ok. Why?

Newbie in Angular, thanks!

Comment: here  you are loading child route `tab1`  into parent `NavigationComponent`  that's the expected behaviour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your  `NavigationComponent`

you need to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: It works, but why? I already have a <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the general app.component. I believed that if I put another router-outlet it should be named.

Comment: you are trying to load child component (`Tab1Component`) inside of Parent  (`NavigationComponent`) , in your app component  `<router-outlet>` will load Parent and  `<router-outlet>` inside will load `Tab1Component` , you can see when your inspect the page

Comment: Ok, so when I declare childs routes, the parent needs <router-outlet></router-outlet>. And I must have so many router-outlets as levels. Thanks! I have been 4 hours with this.